# how to display cameracview in popOvewView in ipad

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

Hi for all i am using popoverController displaying for camera view but i am not getting camera view anybody please help me here s my code.

```
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls=NO;
picker.delegate = nil;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;

UIViewController *containerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
containerController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(768, 750);
[containerController.view addSubview:picker.view];

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]   initWithContentViewController:containerController];

self.popoverController = popover;          
popoverController.delegate = self;          

[popover release];          
CGPoint point = {760,750}; 
CGSize size = {760,750};

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, size.width, size.height) 
                                   inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

here i am getting empty popoverView? video is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the issue. Please check with this code:

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls=NO;
picker.delegate = nil;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(768, 750);

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]   initWithContentViewController:picker];

self.popoverController = popover;          
popoverController.delegate = self;          

[popover release];          
CGPoint point = {760,750}; 
CGSize size = {760,750};

[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, size.width, size.height) inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```